Distorted display in the 3D chart (Highcharts)
I am trying to display a line in a 3D chart with highcharts.
Unfortunately, the view is distorted because the distance between the individual ticks is different for each axis.
Here is an example image:

Is there a way to synchronize the distance?
“xAxis”: {
  “minRange”: 100,
  “tickInterval”: 20,
  “gridLineWidth”: 1,
  “title”: {
    “text”: “X”
  }
}

I am currently trying to display the axis with the same tickInterval, but it is not working.
I have tried to scale the axis equally using defined widths/heights and equal min/max. However, I would like the chart to adapt responsively and not have to specify fixed pixel sizes.

This is very difficult to achieve because it is influenced by many factors such as container dimensions, 3D settings: alpha, beta, depth, and axis settings: min, max tickInterval / tickPixelInterval. And the final effect will be ticks with large decimal values: for example: 3.9333333333333
